# so I cannot figure out why there is a centered bullet point right above the "certificates, references and letters of rec" help pls

Tags: itemize

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
        {\begin{itemize}
                \newcommmand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
                \item Training and experience in managing and supervising both a probation (including adult drug court, sex offender, juvenile, and regular adult) client caseload as well as a workers' compensation client caseload
            \end{itemize}
        }
        \vspace{4pt}
    }
    {\begin{itemize}
            \newcommmand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
            \item Completion of ECO/LSIP training
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \vspace{4pt}
}
{\begin{itemize}
    \newcommmand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
    \item Proficient in administration of urinalysis and swab testing
\end{itemize}
}
\vspace{2pt}
}
{\begin{itemize}
\newcommmand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
\item Qualified in successfully navigating Eclipse/ICON and JPod
\end{itemize}
}

\vspace{9pt}
}

\end{section}
\begin{center}
\begin{textit}

\normalfont \textit{Certificates, references and letters of recommendation available upon request.}
\end{textit}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The provided code is not compilable. Use `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}`, not `\newcommmand`…  There are too many `}`. Remove `\end{section}`. With clean code, no problem here. Maybe it's due to the `documentclass` you use?

Answer (score 1):

You get the bullet because your code is faulty. For example your `\newcommmand` has three `m` in it. So you get lots of errors which you shouldn't ignore. After such errors the output is quite arbitrary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\checkmark}
\begin{itemize}
 \item Training and experience in managing and supervising both a probation (including adult drug court, sex offender, juvenile, and regular adult) client caseload as well as a workers' compensation client caseload

\item Completion of ECO/LSIP training

\item Proficient in administration of urinalysis and swab testing


\item Qualified in successfully navigating Eclipse/ICON and JPod
\end{itemize}

\bigskip
\textit{Certificates, references and letters of recommendation available upon request.}

\end{document}
```